# MongoDB Change stream, how can i write different varient of match function without using json format

Tags: c#, mongodb, changestream

I am trying to write mongodb changestream in c#. I was finding a way to write match function in my pipeline variable without using bson or json format.
My code write now is watching to a particular field in a document.
Here is my code.

```
using MongoDB.Bson;
using MongoDB.Driver;
using System;

namespace changeStream
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            MongoClient dbClient = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017");
            var database = dbClient.GetDatabase("mydb");
            var collection = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("userID");

            var options = new ChangeStreamOptions { FullDocument = ChangeStreamFullDocumentOption.UpdateLookup };

    

              var pipeline = new EmptyPipelineDefinition<ChangeStreamDocument<BsonDocument>>().Match("{ operationType: { $in: [ 'insert', 'delete' ,'update']} $and:[ { 'updateDescription.updatedFields.mainID': { $exists: true }}]}");
            var cursor = collection.Watch<ChangeStreamDocument<BsonDocument>>(pipeline, options);
            int count = 0;
            var enumerator = cursor.ToEnumerable().GetEnumerator();
            while (enumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                
                ChangeStreamDocument<BsonDocument> doc = enumerator.Current;
                count++;
                var time = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss tt");
                Console.WriteLine(count+" "+time+" "+doc.DocumentKey);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

as you can see my match is in bson format, i dont want to use bson, is there any other way to write the similar code,
here is something i found ,

```
 Flux<ChangeStreamEvent<TestObject>> changeStream = mongoTemplate.changeStream(newAggregation(match(where("operationType").is("update").and("updateDescription").exists(true))),TestObject.class,ChangeStreamOptions.empty(),"testObject");
```

I want my code to look something like this instead of bson.

Comment: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66640170/4368485) might help you